# Ruby on Rails: hash.each {} issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Here is my code:

```
records_hash = records[:id].inject({}) { |result,h|
  if result.has_key?(h)
    result[h] += 1
  else
    result[h] = 1
  end
  result
}

@test2 = records_hash.each{|key,value| puts "#{key} is #{value}"}
```

My output should look like this:

```
bozo is 3
bubba is 4
bonker is 5
```

But it renders on the page (`<%= @test2 %>`) as this:

```
bozo3bubba4bonker5
```

I've tried .each_key & .each-value with similar blocks and they all return the same string above.  I run the same code in IRB and it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the each method to build your string. What you want is the map method. each method returns the hash and map returns the value of the block.

You want something like this:

```
@test2 = records_hash.map { |k,v| "#{k} is #{v}" }
```

Also, you shouldn't be building view code like this, unless it is a simple string. Your example implies you want each unique element on each line. So your view should be like this:

```
<% @records_hash.each do |k,v| %>
<%= "#{k} is #{v}" %>
<% end -%>
```

If your view is an HTML one, you'll want some separator between each line as well:

```
<% @records_hash.each do |k,v| %>
<%= "#{k} is #{v}" %><br/>
<% end -%>
```

or

```
<ul>
  <% @records_hash.each do |k,v| %>
  <li><%= "#{k} is #{v}" %></li>
  <% end -%>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, `puts` returns nil.

What you want to do is:

```
@test2 = ""
@test2 = records_hash.each { |k,v| s<< "#{k} is #{v}" }
```

or something similar.

Edit: What you're assigning to `@test2` in your code sample is the return value of the `.each` block.

Comment: @test2 = records_hash.each{|key,value| key} also returns the string mentioned above, though, even though the return value should be |key|, right?

Comment: puts returning nil is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Enumerable.each returns the original collection that each was called on. The return value of the block is irrelevant. As said above, if you want to use the block's return value, you want records_hash.map.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put that in your view, rather than assigning it to a variable.